# Resolving a path to an image file

Tags: java, android

I have an imageView i am trying to set an image to based on the file path of an image the user selects from their gallery. I put the path into a database and then i pass that path into another activity to set the imageView to display. The path comes back at all steps as

```
/external/images/media/23
```

I have used multiple toasts to check the path in the activity before i pass the path, after receiving the path by the called method so i know the path is being sent from activity to activity correctly. However when i use the following code to set the imageView nothing appears.

```
File imgFile;
//Bitmap moviePic;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_movie_view);


    Bundle income = getIntent().getExtras();

    if(income != null)
    {
        mTitle = income.getString("title");
        mYear = income.getString("year");
        id = income.getLong("id");
        mPath = income.getString("path");

    }

    Toast.makeText(this, "path: " + mPath, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    imV = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.movieImage);
    //moviePic = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mPath);
    imgFile = new File(mPath);

    imV.setImageURI(Uri.fromFile(imgFile));
    //imV.setImageResource(R.drawable.top);

    mVT = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.movieViewTitle);
    mVT.setText(mTitle);

    mVY = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.movieViewYear);
    mVY.setText(mYear);

    delete = (Button) findViewById(R.id.deleteMovie);
    delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent deleting = new Intent();
            deleting.putExtra("Id", id);
            setResult(RESULT_OK, deleting);
            finish();
        }

    });
}
```

My guess is that im doing something wrong with the file path. Below is the code i use to resolve the path.

```
imgV.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent addImage = new   
Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_PICK);
            addImage.setType("image/*");

            startActivityForResult(addImage, 1);
        }
    });


}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent)
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);

    switch(requestCode)
    {
    case 1:
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK)
        {
            Uri image = intent.getData();
            imgV.setImageURI(image);
            moviePath = image.getPath();
            Toast.makeText(this, moviePath, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}

}
```

To find the image files i used the android emulator, browsed to google images and downloaded one or two. When i look in the DDMS It placed them in the mnt\sdcar\download\ folder which is obviously different than the path they are resolving to using the image.getPath() method. Is there another way i should be resolving the path? Or is there something im missing with the way the emulator file path works.